# Android Update Setting and quit app after clicking on notification

Tags: android, eclipse, notifications

I'm coding an android app for my school, and i have a little problem with notifications:
My app checks if the homepage was updated (date of page is newer than date of last view) in background. If the page was updated, the app builds a notifications (till here it works fine) with 2 options: Dismiss or show (also works). "Show" works fine, but my problem is "Dismiss" because it has to update the date in settings and it should quit then, but it's always showing the last opened activity.

I'm having an Activity which manages this with Intent extras:

```
public class ***********Handler extends Activity {

        String EXTRA_ACTION = "de.xorg.*****.ACTION";
        String EXTRA_VPDATE = "de.xorg.*****.VPDATE";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ntd);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String todo = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ACTION);  //Action from Notification ("D" or "S")
    String date = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_VPDATE);  //New date
    if(todo.toLowerCase().contains("d")) {     
        //update date value
        Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putString("readDate", date);
        editor.commit();

        // Remove notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(0);

        // Quit app (1st method)  [I'm only using one in real code, but both aren't working]
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // Quit app (2nd method)
        finish();
    } else {
        //update date value
        Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putString("readDate", date);
        editor.commit();

        // Remove notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(0);

        //Set theme (not important now)
        Boolean BeanUI = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("bean", false);
                String URL;
                if(BeanUI) {
                        URL = "*****" + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("klasse", "") + "&fc=ffffff&bc=000000";
                } else {
                        URL = "*****" + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("klasse", "");
                }

                String EXTRA_URL = "de.xorg.*****.MESSAGE";
                String EXTRA_NAME = "de.xorg.*****.MESSAGENAME";
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, InternetViewer.class);
                intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, URL);
                intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, ",Vertretungsplan");
            startActivity(intent2);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the code which creates the notification:

```
// I've censored all private values with ***'s
// CheckService.MC = Context of main activity
// CheckService.NM = NotificationManager
public static void PostNotification(String text, String datum) {
                Intent intentS = new Intent(CheckService.MC, ***************Handler.class);
                Intent intentD = new Intent(CheckService.MC, ***************Handler.class);

                String EXTRA_ACTION = "de.xorg.*****.ACTION";
                String EXTRA_DATE = "de.xorg.*****.VPDATE";

                intentS.putExtra(EXTRA_ACTION, "S");
                intentS.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, datum);
                intentD.putExtra(EXTRA_ACTION, "D");
                intentD.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, datum);
                PendingIntent pIntentD = PendingIntent.getActivity(CheckService.MC, 0, intentD, 0);
                PendingIntent pIntentS = PendingIntent.getActivity(CheckService.MC, 0, intentS, 0);

                // Build notification
                Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(CheckService.MC)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vertretung)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntentS)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.anzeigen, "Show", pIntentS)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.gelesen, "Dismiss", pIntentD).build();

                CheckService.NM.notify(0, n);
}
```

I've tried to do it with »`finish()`;« and with »`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`« both aren't working.

Why doesn't that work? Is there a different (better) way to update the setting?

Comment: In the future, rather than linking to a third party website to display your code, you should embed the most relevant parts into your post.

Comment: @adneal
I thought it's too much code for here :S